# MySQL statistics : 0 vs NULL to store and handle empty / 0 values?

Tags: mysql, null, statistics, int

I plan to use huge tables with columns that stores only unsigned integers. Only TYNY, MEDIUM, INT or BIG according to their known min/max values. These tables will mainly contain zeros. I will have to perform lots of operations like SUM, AVG, COUNT, MIN etc MAX to generate some useful statistics.

What MySQL column type should I use in order to store and / or handle a huge amount of intergers that would generally be empty / 0 values? Is there a column type that would optimize calculation speed or disk space between theses :

Columns of type INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL, that stores NULL by default which is considered as a numeric 0?

Columns of type INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', which store a numeric '0' by default?

Thank you

Comment: NULL is not considered a numeric 0; most aggregate functions ignore NULL values, rather than treat them as 0 (it is only `SUM` that _effectively_ treats NULL as 0.).

Comment: To be specific, if you have values `0, 1, 3`, the average will be `4/3 = 1.333`. But if you have `NULL, 1, 3`, the average will be `4/2 = 2` because the null value is ignored.

Comment: So it really depends on how you want the empty values to be handled by statistical functions.

Comment: OK then by default, i need to use NOT NULL default '0'. But let's say I have columns that I only need to perform various filtered SUMs on it. Let's say there is 20 millions rows, 80 % percent are 0 values. Would I use NULL values instead of zeros in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure whether NULL values would speed you up or slow you down when it comes to `SUM` operations; while sum won't be adding null's (barring some "under to hood" non-obvious MySQL optimization) it still would likely have to visit every null value to see if it should be added. In general, I think I have heard nullable int (and other nullable fixed-size data type) fields have slightly more overhead; but if you need to be able to discern between "0 recorded" and "no value recorded" nullability is indispensable.